# C#: Support both HTTP & socket interface

Tags: c#, sockets, http

I'm developing an application in C# which should support requests from both HTTP clients & on sockets. Idea is to let users access functionality using HTTP and use sockets for IPC.

Is it possible to have both these interfaces supported in a process?

Comment: Side note: if you re-word your question like "can I use HTTP and custom protocols in my application" you may see answer yourself... HTTP protocol and sockets are 2 different layers of network stack...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Windows Communication Foundation for the .NET framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx

With it, you can host your application in IIS and offer both TCP and HTTP endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible. You probably would open a socket manually for your custom transport, and use an HTTP server library to expose an HTTP endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have both these interfaces supported in a process?

Yes.

You can read the incoming data as a string, try to parse it using an HTTP library and then decide what to do based on whether it is or not.